# sqlalchemy saving my df values as text type and i want varchar

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

i have a table in pandas df

```
main_id  p_x   p_y  flag   score
  1       10    20    Y    2.3333
  2       20    30    N    1.653
  3       39    2     Y    6.56546
  1       45    300   Y    2.345
```

i want to store this in mysql database.

and i am using `sqlalchemy` for this.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine_name = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://'+username+':'+password+'@'+hostname+'/'+dbname, echo=False)

df.to_sql(name='table_name', con=engine_name, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

it is getting succesfully created in my database.
BUT MY MAJOR PROBLEM IS

WHEN I DO `describe table_name` in  mysql.

```
+---------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| main_id             | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| p_x                 | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| p_y                 | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flag                | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| score               | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

the field has type `text`

BUT I WANTED `VARCHAR(40)` type for column's `main_id  p_x   p_y  flag`

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify column data type, by default panda uses TEXT:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import String
df.to_sql(name='table_name', con=engine_name, if_exists = 'append', index=False, 
        dtype={'main_id': String, 'p_x': String,  'p_y': String  'flag': String})
```

[sql-data-types](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-data-types)